# Is it possible load a cshtml file in an iframe on non-cshtml page?

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe, razor

I'm working on an outlook 365 app for the web client of outlook. In outlook, you can define a button above the email that opens a panel when clicked. This panel is basically and iframe. The issue is, I need to point that frame at a cshtml file, which you can't do unless the page the iframe is on is also a cshtml file from what I understand.

My question is though, is there a way to load a cshtml file in an iframe on a page that is just a regular, plain html file? If the answer is no, as I suspect it is, is there a different way of doing this or is there a way to get around this?

I've searched high and low on google to try and even find an answer and there is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the cshtml view through the asp.net routing

```
<iframe src="/controller/Action"></iframe>
```

if you want to be able to call views without calling actions 
you need to override  *HandleUnknownAction*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8372820/1551411

Comment: Can I put this iframe in a regular html file? Or does it need to be an asp file?

Comment: Yes, this is html, the server will generate html code from the cshtml file and send it to the client.